# ANT AjcTask and Java 8 -parameters

Tags: java, ant, java-8, aspectj

I want to have both:

1. the Java 8 feature of parameter names per reflection. Compiler argument -parameters
2. AspectJ compilation via ANT.

When i build my project in Eclipse, it seems to work, to set that compiler option and use the AspectJ builder.

But in ANT, i can't see how to do it.
The iajc task does not accept the `<compilerarg value="-parameters" />` element.

Hints?

thx
Frank

Comment: I use the latest aspectjtools.jar 1.8.5 or the developers snapshot aspectj-DEVELOPMENT-20150128122400.jar

Comment: I created this bug report: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=462146

Answer (score 0):

It was a bug:
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=462146

it is solved now, see developers snapshot.